# How to implement decrease indentation in HTML JavaScript custom text formatter?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, execcommand

I am working with a custom text formatter component. I used the code below to implement other functionalities (bold, italic, indent etc.,), Bbut I didn't find decrease indentation here.

```
document.execCommand(aCommandName, aShowDefaultUI, aValueArgument)
```

How would I implement this?

Answer (score 5):

There's the indent and outdent execCommand function for tabbing. Like such:

Indent -- `doc.execCommand('indent', true, null);`

Outdent -- `doc.execCommand('outdent', true, null);`